# How can I do to make clickable an url in a string?

Tags: reactjs

Hello I have that code :

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [myString, setMyString] = useState("Hello I use https://www.google.com/")
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{myString}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This link [https://www.google.com/](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) is not clickable, you can see that here :

[The full project](https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-fast-5yvf5d?file=/src/App.js:0-268)

How can I do to make it clickable ?

Comment: A URL isn't a link. An anchor element is a link. You should not make random elements clickable.

Comment: That doesn't look like a likely duplicate, no.   @Peter, this would be most easily done by preprocessing the text to include the anchor tags; is that a possibility for you, or does it need to be done on the fly in the front end?

Comment: From your comment below I surmise that you either need to isolate your URLs in your data or parse them out using a regex in the React app.

Comment: Does your url always start with `http`or `https`?

Comment: I have both http and https

Comment: Can it be `example.com` without http?

Comment: no only with http or https

Comment: There is no link at all in the code, hence I only expect it to not to have any clickable link.

Answer (score 3):

Since url can't contains space, you can split the string by space and use regex to validate url

Add count prefix to link key because if same links occur key duplicate error is thrown

```js
const urlRegex = /https?:\/\/(.\.?)+\..+/

const ReplaceURL = (str) => {
  const texts = str.split(' ')
    .reduce((acc, text)=>{
      if (urlRegex.test(text)){
        acc.array.push(acc.text)
        acc.urls.push(text)
        acc.text = ''
        
        return acc
      }
  
      acc.text += ` ${text} `
      
      return acc
    }, {array:[], urls:[], text:''})
  
  if (texts.text)
    texts.array.push(texts.text)
    
  const duplicateLinksCount = {}
    
  const links = texts.urls.map((url)=>{
    if (!duplicateLinksCount[url]) duplicateLinksCount[url] = 0
    
    duplicateLinksCount[url] += 1
    
    const key = `${duplicateLinksCount[url]}_${url}`
    
    return <a href={url} key={key}>{url}</a>
  })
    
  const merged = []
  
  for (let i = 0; i < texts.array.length; i+=1){
    merged.push(texts.array[i])
    if (links[i]) merged.push(links[i])
  }
  
  return merged
}
      
      
const App = () => {
  const [myString, setMyString] = React.useState("Hello I use https://www.google.com/ url: http://example.com same url http://example.com")
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{ReplaceURL(myString)}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
const domNode = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domNode);
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your link in an anchor tag and set the href attribute to its relative address.

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const link = "https://www.google.com";
  const myString = "Hello I use ";
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox </h1>
      <h2>
        {myString}
        <a href={link}>{link}</a>.
      </h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I cannot do that ... because it is an example but in my string I have at least ten urls and I got that from a database

Comment: Peter, that doesn't explain your problem. Please update your question post to be more clear about why you think you can't create standard anchor links.

Comment: You'd still make your links clickable through anchor tags. As isherwood mentioned. You need to isolate your urls and then pass each anchor tag. One way you could do that is parse using regex, push each url into an array, using .map or forEach and render each in its own URL tag. 

```["url", "url2", "url3"].map((url)=>{
<a href={url}>{url}</a>
})

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not confessed why you have to use State for this. But you can achieve your desired result by doing the following.

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [myString, setMyString] = useState("Hello I use https://www.google.com/"); 
  
  let result = myString.split(' ');
  const URL  = result[3];
 
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1> <a href={URL}> {URL}</a></h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You can't do that because `myString` contains `Hello I use `

Comment: It now only returns the URLs.  The Question Formation is not clear.

Comment: OP said https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74933043/how-can-i-do-to-make-clickable-an-url-in-a-string/74933258#comment132234996_74933180